# How to create a map of the floors that the user could reserve?

Tags: python, java, reactjs, django, angular

I came up with a space management application for each floor and building. I would like it to be a web application.

After logging in, the user could select the building, floor and the floor map should be displayed. By pressing on a room, he can reserve a desk in it.

How could I implement this "map with desks to reserve" in Django or in Angular or maybe in something else it would be easier? I found only solutions with using google maps, that is not what I am looking for.

[Example of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnOeX.jpg)

Comment: If you have room-plans of your floors you could save the specific location of the desks/rooms and then have a custom script to show a `Reserve`  button ontop of the specific locations. Your data could look something like this: `{name: 'quiet room a44', x: 200, y: 120}`

Comment: @Laisender Sounds nice. I have floor plans like that. Do you know any tool to create such a display with a map on the website?

Comment: I don't know a Tool but its probably not hard to do it by yourself. If you give me some time I could come up with a answer in this thread.

Comment: Sounds like a challenge, great. I would like to code it until November, so there is a lot of time: P

Answer (score 2):

Proof of concept using Javascript, CSS and HTML. I made it responsive so the buttons are always at the correct location.

```js
// The image
const img = document.getElementById('floor1');

// The wrapper
const wrapper = document.getElementById('floor1wrapper');

// These are the pixel coordinates of the original image size, we will scale them down to be responsive later on.
const rooms = [{
    name: 'Room A11',
    x: 192,
    y: 108,
    available: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Room A12',
    x: 615,
    y: 108,
    available: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Room A13',
    x: 867,
    y: 108,
    available: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Room A14',
    x: 77,
    y: 400,
    available: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Room A15',
    x: 380,
    y: 400,
    available: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Room A16',
    x: 740,
    y: 350,
    available: false,
  },
];

window.addEventListener('load', initRooms);
window.addEventListener('resize', initRooms);

initRooms();

function initRooms() {
  const scalingFactor = img.offsetWidth / img.naturalWidth;

  // remove old buttons
  document.querySelectorAll('#floor1wrapper .room-btn').forEach((button) => {
    button.remove()
  });
  
  // add new buttons
  for (let room of rooms) {
    let button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = room.name;
    
    button.style.top = (room.y * scalingFactor) + 'px';
    button.style.left = (room.x * scalingFactor) + 'px';
    button.classList.add('room-btn');
    
    if(!room.available) button.disabled = true;
    
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      alert(room.name + ' booked.');
    });
    
    wrapper.appendChild(button);

  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.room-btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 2px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="floor1wrapper">
  <img id="floor1" src="https://i.imgur.com/DwARfDw.jpeg" />
</div>
```